# LocalGPO compare fails with error

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I was trying to run LocalGPO on my Windows 7 system with its "/Compare" option to compare the current policies with that of a backup. However, the process fails with an error in a Windows Powershell window:

> File
>   C:\SETUPGCB{5653F460-EF17-4E5A-AD23-CB535B495411}\LocalConfig\CompareLocalConfig.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this
>   system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details. At
>   line:1 char:37
>   + .\LocalConfig\CompareLocalConfig.ps1 <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

For reference, "C:\SETUPGCB{5653F460-EF17-4E5A-AD23-CB535B495411}" is the GPO backup that I am comparing the current system configuration to.

What specifically do I need to do to successfully run LocalGPO's compare function?

Thanks!

Comment: I wish you the best of luck. We tried using LocalGPO, but we eventually had to give up.

Comment: `CompareLocalConfig.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.`  What's your scripts execution policy for PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PowerShell script execution policy is preventing the script from executing.

From an elevated Powershell prompt execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and you'll be able to execute unsigned scripts.